# In SQL Reporting Services, is it possible to retrieve a certain value from a dataset, depending on values of multiple other columns in the same row?

Tags: reporting-services

In SQL Reporting Services, is it possible to retrieve a certain value from a dataset, depending on values of **multiple** other columns in the same row?

So, if this was my dataset:

```
Id    | Name      | Number | Score
1     | "John"    | 16     | 22
2     | "Jane"    | 64     | 24
3     | "John"    | 20     | 18
```

I would like to have some sort of 'where' clause, so I can retrieve all/the value(s) where `Name == 'John'` and `Number == 16` for example. This would then return `22`.

I've tried LookUpSet, but that will only compare one other column value. I need to compare two.

Comment: Are your "WHERE" clause values fixed, or do they vary depending on other values in the row?

Comment: Good question. They won't be fixed. One value is another value in the row (i.e. "John"), while another will actually be a value from another dataset (but I can get around that with a hidden parameter).

Comment: Okay. So what are you trying to return here?  Is it a single value or the entire row?  And what behaviour do you want with non-matches?  Exclude the entire row or return a particular default value?

Comment: A single value would be enough, and a default value is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the way the Lookup functions work is to use expressions for the comparison. So you can do something like this if I understand your problem correctly:

=Lookup(Fields!Name.Value+"-"+CStr(Fields.Number.Value), Fields!Name.Value + "-" + CStr(Fields.Number.Value), Fields!Score.Value,"Dataset2")

Comment: Just a side-note the `Lookup()` function is only available on SSRS 2008 R2 and above.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new Tablix based on your DataSet, you could add a column based off the following expression:

```
Iif(Fields!Name.Value = "John" & Fields!Number.Value = Parameters!Number.Value, Fields!Score, 0)
```

This would return the value of the Score column when the value of the Name column is "John" and the Number matches your hidden parameter that you mentioned earlier, and 0 when it's not matched.  You could also couple this with a **Visibility** expression on the Row like so:

```
Iif(Fields!Name.Value = "John" & Fields!Number.Value = Parameters!Number.Value, false, true)
```

This would hide the rows that don't match your desired value.  You could also quite easily have the Name value passed in as a parameter too, if that would suit.

Alternatively, if you actually want to filter the DataSet itself, you could specify these expressions on the **DataSet Properties** > **Filter** tab, rather than at the Tablix level - it depends if you need to re-use your DataSet elsewhere in the report.